# SQL crear rango de fechas entre dos columnas

Tags: sql

tengo un problema con una consulta. Estoy intentando generar un rango de fechas entre dos columnas.
Esta es mi tabla inicial;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el  resultado que busco seria este;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seria posible conseguir el resultado deseado sin crear tablas adicionales?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: en que motor estas trabajando?

Comment: Depende de la versión de base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una posible solución, puede que sea algo imaginativa pero funciona, se basa en conseguir números donde restas de la fecha final, y la sentencia lo logra a partir de un id de un tabla, en este caso de `sys_columns`.

```
SELECT b.id, b.Name, DATEADD(DAY, fecha - 1, start_date) as date, start_date, end_date
FROM    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS fecha
          FROM sys.columns c
        ) Fechas
INNER JOIN tabla b on Fechas.fecha <= b.end_date
WHERE   fecha - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, start_date, end_date)
ORDER BY Name, date
```